# Rebulding Database not showing previous analytics after upgrade

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, reporting

I have upgraded from Sitecore 9 to 9.2 recently. Looking into the database I see all interactions being written to xDB. But from the date of upgrade, the UI has not been updated on Experience Analytics. i.e. [image: analytics]

I have tried rebuilding the reporting database and still no update to the UI. How may I update this UI to add in the new xDB records? I am using a CM CD setup.

Comment: Did you deploy your marketing definitions?

Comment: Yes, I have deployed marketing definitions,rebuild indexes, rebuild link database

Comment: @MarkCassidy Is there any way to ensure there has been no data corruption?

Comment: Did you happen to re-enable not indexing anonymous contacts when you copied in the 9.2 xConnect xml config files?

Comment: @ChrisAuer nope

Comment: have you rebuild the xDB solr cores via `XConnectSearchIndexer -rr`

Comment: yes, still same error

Comment: Are you on Sitecore Slack?

Comment: No. I think I will do a clean installation of Sitecore 9.2 and integrate Solr 7.5 and that should work. I'll observe any differences.